# Sikuli automation in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, automation, ubuntu-12.04, sikuli

Am trying to install sikuli in ubuntu 12.4 
followed the steps mentioned in the below site

http://www.verious.com/tool/installing-sikuli-automation-tool-on-ubuntu-11-10/

java installed in the ubuntu is

```
~$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

sikuli-ide is successfully loading and while i trying to capture an image on the screen am getting following errror

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/ushusadmin/sikuli/Sikuli-IDE/libs/libVisionProxy.so: libml.so.2.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1965)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1890)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1851)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:795)
at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1062)
at com.wapmx.nativeutils.jniloader.NativeLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLoader.java:44)
at org.sikuli.script.TextRecognizer.(TextRecognizer.java:24)
at org.sikuli.ide.NamingPane.getFilenameFromImage(NamingPane.java:55)
at org.sikuli.ide.CaptureButton.update(CaptureButton.java:149)
at org.sikuli.script.CapturePrompt.notifyObserver(CapturePrompt.java:44)
at org.sikuli.script.CapturePrompt$1.mouseReleased(CapturePrompt.java:197)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Componen

t.java:6505)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Window.processEvent(Window.java:2022)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(

Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
```

How can i get rid of this error.Am spending my days for rectifying this error and really fed up :-( Experts pelase help me

Answer (score 5):

I noticed this in your stack trace:

`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/ushusadmin/sikuli/Sikuli-IDE/libs/libVisionProxy.so: libml.so.2.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

The complaint about libml.so.2.1 not being found makes me suspect you have an older version of Sikuli.

So, I would suggest using the latest Sikuli release (1.0.1), and making sure you have at least OpenCV 2.4.0 installed.

Note that Sikuli 1.0.1 depends on OpenCV 2.4.0, whereas the guide you linked is from the days when 2.3.0 was acceptable.

I would try removing the 2.3 version of the libcv-dev package (if that's what you have), and instead install libcv-dev from the opencv2.4 PPA repo:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gijzelaar/opencv2.4
```

Also, I noticed that the Sikuli folks have posted a special build of libVisionProxy.so for download; not sure if it's intended to help systems like yours, but could be worth a try if using Sikuli 1.0.1 and OpenCV 2.4.0 don't help.

The file in question is `Sikuli-1.0.1-Supplemental-LinuxVisionProxy.zip` at https://launchpad.net/sikuli/+download

Finally, in case it helps, here are the full steps I used to get Sikuli 1.0.1 up and running on Ubuntu 12.04:

1. Install Oracle JRE (I'm using 1.7.0_51, just like your env)
2. Install OpenCV 2.4.0

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gijzelaar/opencv2.4

   sudo apt-get update

   sudo apt-get libcv-dev
   ```

   Alternatively, you can probably achieve the same by building/installing OpenCV 2.4.0 from source, per the steps at:

   http://karytech.blogspot.com/2012/05/opencv-24-on-ubuntu-1204.html

   Note when I tried that, I omitted the steps to install the QT packages and removed "-D WITH_QT=ON" from my cmake command when building OpenCV.
3. Install Tesseract 3:

   `sudo apt-get install libtesseract3`
4. Download sikuli-setup.jar and save it to ~/SikuliX
5. Launch sikuli-setup.jar and install Sikuli to ~/SikuliX

   `cd ~/SikuliX && java -jar sikuli-setup.jar`

   I selected the "Pack 1" option and let setup proceed normally.
6. Create a Sikuli script in the IDE and run it.

   Also, I found that running .sikuli projects using the "runIDE -r" option very helpful for troubleshooting dependency problems; that seems to result in more info about the error compared to running the script in the IDE. For example:

   `~/SikuliX/runIDE -r foo.sikuli`

Here are my OS and JRE environment details:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise

$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```